# Evaluate the sum $S = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}{\text{Ci}}\left( {\pi \left( {2n + 1} \right)} \right)} $

Tags: calculus, summation

I am trying to evaluate this sum:$$S = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}{\text{Ci}}\left( {\pi \left( {2n + 1} \right)} \right)} $$
$${\text{Where}}:{\text{Ci}}\left( x \right){\text{ is the cosine integral and Ci}}\left( x \right) =  - \int\limits_x^\infty  {\frac{{\cos \left( t \right)}}{t}dt} $$

I tried this method:$$\eqalign{
  & S = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}{\text{Ci}}\left( {\pi \left( {2n + 1} \right)} \right)}  =  - \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\int\limits_1^\infty  {\frac{{\cos \left( {\pi t\left( {2n + 1} \right)} \right)}}{t}dt} }   \cr 
  &  =  - \int\limits_1^\infty  {\frac{1}{t}dt\left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\cos \left( {\pi t\left( {2n + 1} \right)} \right)} } \right)}  =  - \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_1^\infty  {\frac{1}{t}\sec \left( {\pi t} \right)dt}  \cr} $$

But the last integral is divergent. May I ask for help? Thank you so much.

Comment: How do you figure $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\cos(\pi t(2n+1))$ is equal to $\sec\pi t$? The series doesn't even converge for integer $t$ and I suspect it doesn't converge for most if not all nonzero values of $t$

Comment: @FShrike You're right, i just use WA to find this sum. May be i misdirected? Would you mind giving me some hints?

Comment: I would if I could. Integrals and series are not my strong suit. I would suggest that the series also is equal to: $$-\sum_{n\ge0}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos t}{t+\pi(4n+1)}\,\mathrm{d}t$$Which is maybe more useful (group together the terms like this, $[Ci(\pi)-Ci(3\pi)]+[Ci(5\pi)-Ci(7\pi)]+\cdots$)

Comment: Maybe: $$\sum_{n\ge1}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos t}{\pi(4n-1)-t}\,\mathrm{d}t$$Is more useful. I’m thinking geometric series

Comment: From "phone a friend": the series is equal to: $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{1+x^2}\cdot\operatorname{sech}(\pi x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$Which they believe to be impossible to evaluate nicely. Do you know if this series has a closed form? Where did it come from?